# Why Doesn't Physical Back Button Work The Same As The Application Back Button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am using the following code to implement the back button in the toolbar.

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String seriesLeagueId = String.valueOf( getIntent().getStringExtra( "seriesLeagueId" ) );
                String seriesBowlerId = String.valueOf( getIntent().getIntExtra( "seriesBowlerId", 2 ) );
                String seriesSeriesId = String.valueOf( getIntent().getIntExtra( "seriesSeriesId", 2 ) );

                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("seriesLeagueId",seriesLeagueId);
                intent.putExtra("seriesBowlerId",seriesBowlerId);
                intent.putExtra("seriesSeriesId", seriesSeriesId);
                setResult(1,intent);
                Log.d("PASSING SERIES_ID BACK","Series Id = >>>>" + seriesSeriesId + "<<<<");
                Log.d("PASSING BOWLER_ID BACK","Bowler Id = >>>>" + seriesBowlerId + "<<<<");
                Log.d("PASSING LEAGUE_ID BACK","League Id = >>>>" + seriesLeagueId + "<<<<");
                finish();//finishing activity
            }
        });
```

When I use the physical back button the app crashed and Logcat tells me the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.views.SeriesActivity.onActivityResult(SeriesActivity.java:393)
```

Java line 393 is as follows:

```
String savedLeagueId=data.getStringExtra("seriesLeagueId");
```

But there is nothing wrong with this line as far as I can see.  Here is the code that this belongs too.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Check If Request Code Is The Same As What Is Passed - Here It Is 1
        if(requestCode==1)
        {
            String savedLeagueId=data.getStringExtra("seriesLeagueId");
            String savedBowlerId=data.getStringExtra("seriesBowlerId");
            seriesList.addAll( db.getAllSeries( savedLeagueId, savedBowlerId ) );
        }
    }
```

Now if I rem out the **finish()** in the first snippet the physical back button works correctly, but the toolbar back button doesn't, obviously because it isn't finishing.  When I do a debug I can see that seriesLeagueId = NULL. However this is only when the physical back button is pressed.

Can anyone provide some insight on this issue.

onBackPressed Code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        String seriesLeagueId = String.valueOf( getIntent().getStringExtra( "seriesLeagueId" ) );
        String seriesBowlerId = String.valueOf( getIntent().getIntExtra( "seriesBowlerId", 2 ) );
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("seriesLeagueId",seriesLeagueId);
        intent.putExtra("seriesBowlerId",seriesBowlerId);
        setResult(1,intent);
        finish();//finishing activity
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: You should change the `javascript` tag to `java` tag or `android` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a design decision for the toolbar button action is `navigate up on the stack` and the return button action is `return back in the stack`.

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral

So the default implementation for NavigateUp is to start the parent activity with NEW_TASK flag, while the return button do finish() the current one.

As far I have seen, everyone overrides the toolbar up button to act exactly as the return button.

In your case, override onBackPressed to handle the back button aswell the navigation button.

Comment: Would the onBackPressed need to have the same code as the toolbar back button in order to pass the information back to the previous activity?

Comment: Yes, it does... extract all that code into a method and call the same method both onBackPressed and onNavigationItemClicked

Comment: Awesome, this solved the issue.  This was a great answer and helped me solved quickly.